# Wordpress External URLs

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using external CSS and js files in my WordPress site, like google analytics and HubSpot's plugins. While am checking my score in GTmetrix and another website it shows leverage browser caching and add expire header problems for the above plugins CSS and js files. So I would like to call those files locally on my website. I want to know where I want to change those links. In Which file locations those files are called, how to trace and change them locally. Please help me out.

Thanks,
Gokul.

Comment: Don't do that, read the document carefully for leverage browsing and do it accordingly. Use good rated plugins like wp fastest cache, hummingbird, w3 total cache.

Comment: Dear Ravi, thanks for your reply and activated wp fastest cache even though its showing error for third party plugins. Any other solutions for this one.